# ListBox.DataSource doesn't show data on the list

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, listbox

Help guys, I have a List of Points **List points = new List();** , what I'm trying to do is removing some data from the list. I used a listbox to see whether it works. This is my code:

```
        points.Add(new PointF(50, 100));
        points.Add(new PointF(50, 100));
        points.Add(new PointF(200, 300));
        points.Add(new PointF(100, 200 ));
        points.Add(new PointF(50, 100));
        points.Add(new PointF(100, 200));
        points.Add(new PointF(200, 300));
        points.Add(new PointF(100, 200));
        points.Add(new PointF(200, 300));

        listBox1.DataSource = points;

        float[] sumofxandy = new float[points.Count()];
        for (int x = 0; x < points.Count(); x++)
        {
            sumofxandy[x] = points.ElementAt(x).X + points.ElementAt(x).Y;
        }


        //code that removes data from list starts from here
        float[] difference = new float[points.Count()]; //there is something wrong with this and I don't know what. It has no error but it doesn't make my list to be shown in the listbox.
        for (int i = 0; i <= points.Count(); i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= points.Count(); j++) 
            {

                difference[j] = sumofxandy[i] - sumofxandy[j];
                if (difference[i] == 0) 
                {
                    points.RemoveAt(j);

                    MessageBox.Show("removed");
                }

            }
        } // ends here

        listBox2.DataSource = points;
```

When I erased the code that removes data from the list, the elements inside the list will be shown in the listbox. Help guys

Comment: Do you want to remove duplicates? use `points = points.Distinct().ToList();`.

Comment: also, your code for `sumofXandY` can be rewritten like this: `var SumOfXandY = points.Select(p => p.X + p.Y);`

Comment: Are you using the wrong variable in if (difference[i] == 0)? I get an exception when using 'i', but none when using 'j'.

Comment: Can you explain better what you're really trying to do? what is the criteria to remove the items? remove `duplicate` items?

Comment: @HighCore Yes, I'm trying to remove duplicates. What if the data inside the list are only close like points in difference, because in my project it is still consider to be a duplicate. although it only differs in points.

Comment: @HighCore here is the thing, I have a List that stores PointF data. About 200, those are coordinates. It's from a box detection algorithm, it results coordinates of a box, but it detects a box not once only. so it gives redundant output, but some output may differ in points. Is it possible to be done by using distinct()?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are using the wrong variable in the `if(difference[i] == 0)`?

When using your solution I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException on the line `points.RemoveAt(j);`

```
difference[j] = sumofxandy[i] - sumofxandy[j];
if (difference[i] == 0) 
{
    points.RemoveAt(j);
     MessageBox.Show("removed");
}
```

When the line `if(difference[i] == 0)` are changed to:

```
if(difference[j] == 0)
```

then the code executes successful, with 3 items in listbox2.

EDIT:

As @wdosanjos mentions, you should do your loops with a `<` rather than `<=` since you start counting at zero, and not 1. The last element is really at position Count - 1, since the list are zero indexed.

EDIT:

When I changed the loops to: (notice the change in `<=` to `<`, it does not throw an exception.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < points.Count(); j++)
            {

                difference[j] = sumofxandy[i] - sumofxandy[j];
                if (difference[i] == 0)
                {
                    points.RemoveAt(j);

                    MessageBox.Show("removed");
                 }

            }
        } // ends here
```

This returns two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `for` loops as follows (from `<=` to `<`).  I think you are getting a hidden `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.Count(); i++) 
{
    for (int j = 1; j < points.Count(); j++)
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are modifying the very same list you are iterating over. This may just as easy remove all the points. You should better create a new list for points that should be removed:

```
    //code that removes data from list starts from here
    List<PointF> pointsToRemove = new List<PointF>();
    float[] difference = new float[points.Count()];
    for (int i = 0; i <= points.Count(); i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= points.Count(); j++) 
        {

            difference[j] = sumofxandy[i] - sumofxandy[j];
            if (difference[i] != 0) 
            {
                pointsToRemove.Add(points[j]);

                MessageBox.Show("removed");
            }

        }
    }

    listBox2.DataSource = points.Except(pointsToRemove).ToList();
```